# ngClass not working in my Angular Project

Tags: html, angularjs, angular, typescript, ng-class

I'm trying to make a form with validation, and I am using the following interface to define `FieldError`.

```
export interface FieldError {
  errorAt: string;
  errorMessage: string;
}
```

In my component.html I am using `[ngClass]` to check if the `FieldError.errorAt === 'first_name'` I want to use `text-danger` and if not I want to use `text-muted`.

It looks like following

```html
<div class="form-group text-left">
    <label [ngClass]="{'text-danger':FieldError.errorAt==='first_name','text-muted':FieldError.errorAt!=='first_name'}">First name*</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]='first_name'>
    <small class="text-danger"> First-Name is Required </small>
</div>
```

I understand I can use that, the tertiary operator for `?:`, but even that is not working.

Also My `ngOnInit` has following code:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.FieldError.errorAt = '';
    this.FieldError.errorMessage = '';
}
```

***Note: *** Those are bootstrap classes.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue in stackblitz?

Comment: If it’s solved, tick the check mark next to an answer below.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, So I put a little more time on it, in addition to the last one hour.

So the `FieldError` is an interface and this is the reason that it is not initializing itself, i.e. It should not even have the value.

I need to simply use a Component level object like following, rather than the interface.

```
  FieldError = {
    errorAt: '',
    errorMessage: ''
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

When using interfaces, it defines the type of a variable.

```
public formField: FieldError = {errorAt: '', errorMessage: ''};
```

Then you can use it in ngClass

```
<div class="form-group text-left">
    <label [ngClass]="{'text-danger': formField.errorAt==='first_name','text-muted': formField.errorAt!=='first_name'}">First name*</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]='first_name'>
    <small class="text-danger"> First-Name is Required </small>
</div>
```

The best thing to do would be to use a named variable on the template and then use the template variables to check for validation.

https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#validating-input-in-template-driven-forms

```
<div class="form-group text-left">
    <label [ngClass]="{'text-danger': fname.invalid,'text-muted': fname.invalid}">First name*</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]='first_name' #fname="ngModel">
    <small class="text-danger"> First-Name is Required </small>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I figured that out, right after posting the question,
It can get really irritating, I mean you know the thing, but can't remember.

Comment: I have definitely been there.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ternary operator like below

```
<i class="fa fa-lg fa-fw" [ngClass]="{
'fa-check-square text-primary': collection.includes(vendor.id),
'fa-window-close text-danger': !collection.includes(vendor.id)
}"></i>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Nikhil but as mentioned in the question that didn't solve anything, plus that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Form de [docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass#description):

> The CSS classes are updated as follows, depending on the type of the expression evaluation:

- string - the CSS classes listed in the string (space delimited) are
  added,
- Array - the CSS classes declared as Array elements are added,
- Object - keys are CSS classes that get added when the expression
  given in the value evaluates to a truthy value, otherwise they are
  removed.

when we use some like

```
[ngClass]="{'text-danger': fname.invalid,'text-muted': !fname.invalid}"
```

you're using ngClass as "object" (the expresion result(*) is an object), see that the way is `{'name class':condition,...}`

If you use some like

```
[ngClass]="fname.invalid?'text-danger':'text-muted'"
```

you're using ngClass as "string" (the expresion result(*) is a string) -see that has no `{` `}`-

(*) the expresion enclosed by doble quotes